# Uncaught TypeError: setTimeout(...) is not a function - in a for loop, but it still runs

Tags: javascript

So basically this is supposed make a bunch of eyes blink and move around randomly, with a chance to blink and to move evaluated at an interval. Once the random number generator hits upon the chance to blink for a given eye, I want that eye to close and then open again after a short delay (so it can finish its animation) independently of the other eyes.

```
function eyeMovement(){ /* ---------------Eye Movement--------------*/
var tabOne = document.getElementById('tab-'+ui.tabs[0].tabname);
if (tabOne.style.display == "block"){
    for(var i = 0; i < document.getElementsByClassName("attentionUIEye").length; i++){
        var eyeDiv = document.getElementById("up-"+i+"-attentionUIEye"),
            irisDiv = document.getElementById("up-"+i+"-attentionUIEyeballIris"),
            pupilDiv = document.getElementById("up-"+i+"-attentionUIEyeballPupil"),
            eyeballDiv = document.getElementById("up-"+i+"-attentionUIEyeball"),
            irisHeight = parseFloat(irisDiv.style.height),
            irisWidth = parseFloat(irisDiv.style.width),
            chanceToMove = Math.random()*100,
            chanceToBlink = Math.random()*100,
            eyeballHeight = 0;
        function openEye(){
            eyeballHeight = 40;
            eyeballDiv.style.height = eyeballHeight+'%';
            eyeballDiv.style.top = 50-eyeballHeight/2+'%';
        };
        function closeEye(){
            eyeballHeight = 0;
            eyeballDiv.style.height = eyeballHeight+'%';
            eyeballDiv.style.top = 50-eyeballHeight/2+'%';
        };
        function centerIris(){
            irisDiv.style.top = ((50-parseFloat(irisDiv.style.height)/2)-(parseFloat(eyeballDiv.style.top)-20))+"%";
            irisDiv.style.left = (50-parseFloat(pupilDiv.style.width)/2)+"%";
        };
        function compensateIrisSize(){
            var eyeballHeight = parseFloat(eyeballDiv.style.height);
            
            irisDiv.style.height = 100*100/eyeballHeight/2+'%';
            //irisDiv.style.width = irisDiv.style.height;
        };
        function openEyeTimeout(){
                setTimeout(openEye,200)();    //this is where the problem is.
        };
        function blink(chance){
            if(chanceToBlink < chance){
                closeEye();
                openEyeTimeout();
            };
        };
        function saccade(chance){
            if(chanceToMove < chance){
                var nextPositionX = (Math.random()*80)-(30);
                var nextPositionY = (Math.random()*80)-(40);
                irisDiv.style.left = nextPositionX+"%";
                irisDiv.style.top = nextPositionY+"%";
                //center pupil
                pupilDiv.style.top = (50-parseFloat(pupilDiv.style.height)/2)+"%";
                pupilDiv.style.left = (50-parseFloat(pupilDiv.style.width)/2)+"%";
            };
        };
        if (activities[i].discovered == false){
            saccade(2);
            blink(0.5);
            compensateIrisSize();
            pupilDiv.style.width = 40+"%";
            pupilDiv.style.height = 40+"%";
        } else { 
            closeEye();
        };
    };
};
};
function slowLoop() {
    eyeMovement();
};
setInterval(slowLoop, 33);
```

In the function `openEyeTimeout`, `setTimeout(openEye,200)();` gives the error

> Uncaught TypeError: setTimeout(...) is not a function
>
> at openEyeTimeout (itgame2.js:287)
>
> at blink (itgame2.js:292)
>
> at eyeMovement (itgame2.js:308)
>
> at slowLoop (itgame2.js:319)

In the DOM Inspector in Chrome.

When I try `setTimeout(openEye,200);`, with no (), then there is no error but only the last eye blinks, the others wait until a chance to blink occurs, and they close forever.

If it seems to be working as intended, why is there an error? I'd rather not build atop a faulty foundation.

Comment: Why do you have that `()` *after* the `setTimeout()` call???

Comment: Potential mixup of an IIFE?

Comment: The title of your question is misleading. The **real** problem is what you describe at the end of the question, with only the last eye working. That's because you're creating functions in a loop and not handling the fact that they close over the variables, not their values as of when the functions are created. The linked question's answers explain what's going on, and how to fix it. The error in the title is just because you added `()` for some reason, which **calls** the result of calling `setTimeout`. Since the result of calling `setTimeout` is a number, that fails.

Comment: Unrelated but why on earth are you defining your functions in every single iteration of the loop?

Comment: @Pointy: He/she explains that at the bottom of the question. Sort of.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I see, thanks for pointing out the heart of the matter, I'm going to look into restructuring this now.